# How to call back a modal from another modal?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am writing an application that has one modal passed between many elements. It has an id and class and I only change a view items in the modal depending on the list item the user chooses. However, I have a "delete" button in the modal, and whenever the user selects it, another one pops up and they must select "Yes" or "No" to confirm. Though if they choose yes I want to revert back to the first modal and stop or disable them from clicking delete again.
I came up with a solution but it puts a lock on all the modal's "delete" button and not just the one I selected. So my goal is to figure out a way to reference back to the previous modal that I initiated it from.

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="myForm">
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update or
                            Create</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-form-label">Application Name:</label> <input
                                type="text" class="form-control" id="displayAppName"
                                name="displayAppName" value="" readonly /> <label
                                class="col-form-label">Application Code:</label> <input
                                type="text" class="form-control" id="appcode" name="appcode"
                                value="" readonly /> <label class="col-form-label"> Map
                                Status:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mapStatus"
                                name="mapStatus" value="" readonly /> <label
                                class="col-form-label">Edit Status:</label> <input type="text"
                                class="form-control" id="editStatus" name="editStatus" value=""
                                readonly />


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer" id="dashboardModalFooter">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteGPBtn">Delete</button>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                            id="dashboardCloseModal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                        <a id="modalCreateBtn"> <input type="submit"
                            class="btn btn-primary modal-create" id="createBtn"

                            value="Create" /></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>





    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete Grouping
                        Pattern</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Are you sure you
                        want to delete?</div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="deleteGPYes">Yes</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
            $("#deleteGPBtn").on("click", function(event){


                $("#exampleModal").modal('hide');   //Hides current modal with delete button
                $('#deleteModal').modal('show');    //Displays the are you "sure" modal



            });




            $('#deleteGPYes').on('click',function(){
                //If they select "Yes" I want to somehow disable the button for this specific modal.
                //However, I need to somehow refrence back one modal which I don't know how
                $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');

            });
```

So once they select `#deleteGPBtn` they will then have to choose `#deleteGPYes` in order to disable the "delete" button associated with that list item.

P.S - I tried using jQuery's `find()` or `children()` but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the button shouldn't be a problem, since `id`s are unique.

You can set the `id` of the current modal on a [data attribute](https://api.jquery.com/data/) on the new modal.

```
$("#deleteGPBtn").on("click", function(event) {
  $("#exampleModal").modal('hide'); //Hides current modal with delete button

  // Save calling modal
  $('#deleteModal').data('callback-modal', $('#exampleModal'))
    .modal('show'); //Displays the are you "sure" modal
});


$('#deleteGPYes').on('click', function() {
  //If they select "Yes" I want to somehow disable the button for this specific modal.
  //However, I need to somehow refrence back one modal which I don't know how

  // Read the data attribute
  let $returnTo = $('#deleteModal').data('callback-modal');
  // Limit the button search
  $('#deleteGPBtn', $returnTo).prop('disabled', true);
  $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
  // Show old modal
  $returnTo.modal('show');
  // Cleanup
  $('#deleteModal').removeData('callback-modal');
});
```